# Compiling an independent DLL file using Intel Fortran compiler

Tags: visual-studio, dll, fortran, intel-fortran

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio with Intel Fortran Compiler to compile my DLL files. However, the DLL files cannot be read in another computer. I realised that there are probably some dependency issues where not all the resources are compiled into the DLL file.

May I know how to compile a standalone DLL file that can be read in other computers? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferable solution is to install the necessary dependent DLLs on the other system. For an Intel Visual Fortran DLL you will need the [Intel redistributables](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compilers-redistributable-libraries-by-version), and the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributables for the version of Visual Studio you are using.

If the user of the DLL is not a Fortran program, in most cases you can eliminate DLL dependencies by changing the project property Fortran > Libraries > Use Runtime Library to "Multithreaded /MT". But if a Fortran program will be using the DLL, please don't do this as it can lead to problems when more than one copy of the run-time library is present in the program.